# How to see specific code of preloader in a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the link to the website: [website](http://www.vashistmotors.com/) i am finding detail code of just the preloader / loading circle gif image in start. Please let me know how to do so?

Comment: Use the Inspector of your browser and start with the HTML ... there's code in there `<div id="laoding-mask"> that should get you started.  You should also be able to locate any related CSS and JavaScript with some research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right click on the webpage and press "View page source", you can find the following code towards the beginning:

```
<div id="loading-mask">
  <div class="loading-img"><img alt="img" src="img/preloader.gif" /></div>
</div>
```

Thus, the URL of the image in question is http://www.vashistmotors.com/img/preloader.gif, shown below.

[image]

In the `js/scripts.js` file, it contains this code (which fortunately is commented to tell us what the intent is):

```
////////////////////////////////////////////  
// LOADING
///////////////////////////////////////////  

window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('loading-mask').style.display = 'none';

}
```

which hides the image when the page is loaded.

Comment: Hi this is what i could get from file name script.js window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('loading-mask').style.display = 'none';

    }

Comment: So basically the code which help load the preloader gif is the mentioned in script.js with what you said above ?

Comment: @SamAulakh The preloader gif is already visible part of the page. The mentioned script *hides* the gif that is already present.

Comment: i am actually looking for code which enables this gif to run as preloader

Comment: @SamAulakh You just put the gif on the page and it will be present from the start. You don't need any JavaScript for that. All you need to do is hide it once it is no longer needed.

Comment: Some of my friend asked me this : Could you provide me the detail code of just the loading that has been used for this site? How to answer him?

Comment: Include `<div id="loading-mask"><div class="loading-img"><img alt="img" src="img/preloader.gif" /></div></div>` somewhere in the page to include it, put `window.onload = function () {document.getElementById('loading-mask').style.display = 'none';}` in the script to hide it once the page is fully loaded.